# How to check custom database exist or not in Powershell script

Tags: sxa, powershell-extensions

We have created a custom database **Preview** in Sitecore Sxa. We need to check this database is exist or not through `Sitecore Powershell` script.

Could someone let me know how we can check database exist or not in Sitecore powershell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out the below script, Just replace `master` with your database name.

```
if(($db = Get-Database -Name "master" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
    $db
} else {
    Write-Host "Does not exist."
}
```

Hope it helps!